# Importing data from multiple csv files in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, import, d3.js

I am brand new to D3 and just started working on an a project. My question is this.
I want to import data from 2 csv files in D3 to use them for graph comparisons. The problems I am facing are:

1.How do I import data from multiple csv files.
2.Can I use one array for each csv or does D3 use only one global data array?
 3.Is there a way to choose a certain column from the csv files to import?

Here is an example, I want to import the "oldVer" from each of the files in separate arrays and then use the 2 arrays to work with. Is that posible in D3 and how?

csv 1
time,oldVer,newVer,oldT,newT
1,180930,190394,24,59
2,198039,159094,26,45
3,152581,194032,22,61

csv 2
time,oldVer,newVer,oldT,newT
1,184950,180435,27,26
2,120590,129409,13,13
3,165222,182133,60,54

Again sorry for the dumb question but I have found little feedback on this matter. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 37):

In d3 version 5, you can use `Promise.all` to load multiple csv files. Example:

```
Promise.all([
    d3.csv("file1.csv"),
    d3.csv("file2.csv"),
]).then(function(files) {
    // files[0] will contain file1.csv
    // files[1] will contain file2.csv
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
})
```

[More info about loading csv in d3 v5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49604124/6088109)

[More info about `Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thanks @Abang F, the simplest and clearest demonstration I've seen :)

Comment: Can I use this somehow with a dynamic number of files?

Comment: @blckbird `Promise.all(fileList.map(d3.csv)).then(...)`

Answer (score 17):

You simply call `d3.csv` several times:

```
d3.csv("csv1.csv", function(error1, data1) {
  d3.csv("csv2.csv", function(error2, data2) {
    // do something with the data
  });
});
```

As for your third question, no, D3 will parse everything. There's nothing forcing you to use all the data though, so if you're interested in only one column, just use the data from that.

Comment: Hi Lars, since the objective is to compare the data and thus have both available at the same time, there would be a need to control the flow of execution of these nested asynchronous calls, no? If we do something inside the inner function, there is no guarantee that data1 will be ready. Am I right? I was reading [this](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html). It is talking about node.js but perhaps it would apply.

Comment: Right on spot, I will try it out now. I've read about asynchronous calls before, but cannot say much, I just have to try it out. Thank you for the quick responce guys.

Comment: IF I am right here, in the link I referenced, I believe you want 7.2.2 Control flow pattern #2, where "...we just want to take a small set of operations, launch them all in parallel and then do something when all of them are complete."

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes No -- this is exactly what the nesting takes care of. I'm sending the request for the second CSV only when the first request is complete, so inside the second handler function *both* are guaranteed to be available.

Comment: I see now...the inner call will only run when the data returns from the outer call. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Guys I've been away for a long while after I did this post. I'm more familiar with things now and see how this could apply. Will try it in a few days, hope it works. Didn't expect nesting to work, but seems logical. Again I will respond with feedback. Thanks again for the responds and sorry for the late response by me.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I finally got around by using the queue.js. Worked like a charm. Problems with other stuff still coming up, but I have the working code on another question I did about tooltips in case anyone is interested of its use.

Answer (score 15):

You could use a d3 [queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue/blob/master/README.md#queue) to load the files simultaneously. An example;

```
d3.queue()
.defer(d3.csv, "file1.csv")
.defer(d3.csv, "file2.csv")
.await(function(error, file1, file2) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Oh dear, something went wrong: ' + error);
    }
    else {
        doStuff(file1, file2);
    }
});
```

Comment: does this work for json as well? e.g. 
 ``` d3.queue()/* to load multiple datasets */
    .defer(d3.json, "data1")
    .defer(d3.json, "data2")
    .await(function(error, data1, data2) {
      if (error) {
          console.log('Something went wrong: ' + error);
      }
      else {
          //stuff for graph
      }
  });```

Comment: Great way of doing that!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your part 3,

> 3. Is there a way to choose a certain column from the `csv` files to
>      import?

No, you cannot load in part of a `CSV`. You can, however, load in the entire `CSV` file and selectively use one column from it. You can refer to `data.newVer` to utilize the `newVer` column data.