# How to load multiple csv files and use them mixed with each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having issues understanding d3. I'm trying to load a bunch of .csv files while have a timestamp in the left column and an integer in the right column, representing the number of people present at any point in time in a classroom (every classroom has its own .csv).

Now the idea is to make a pie chart representing a day's worth of people present divided between the multiple classrooms. For example, 65 % classroom 1, 23 % classroom 2 and 12 % classroom 3.

I'm struggling to understand how i would even go about reading these, apparently everything inside the d3.csv() parser is outside the scope of everything outside of it, which is very counter intuitive. I cannot access the things I'm parsing from outside the .csv() method, which is weird, because I'm reading the .csv files as following:

```
var files = ["Bibliotheek S2.csv","Bibliotheek S8.csv","Euclides S23.csv","Lovelace Ledeganck.csv","Mercator S8.csv","Nadar S8.csv","Ortelius S8.csv","Practicum S2.csv","S12.csv","Thetis INW.csv","Turing S9.csv","Van Straelen S8.csv","Zuse S9.csv"];

dt = {};
files.forEach(function(f){
    d3.csv("lokalen/"+f,function(data){
        dt[f] = data;
    });
});
```

How would i continue with this? I'm absolutely lost here.

Thanks, 
Milan

Comment: You could nest the calls...check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842384/importing-data-from-multiple-csv-files-in-d3).

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite that everything within the scope of `d3.csv()` is unavailable: `d3.csv()` is asynchronous. In a nutshell, code in the `d3.csv()` callback isn't executed until *after* the csv file downloads. But, code after `d3.csv()` executes immediately. In your case, if you try to access `dt` immediately after your `files.forEach` loop, the files will not have downloaded yet.

To get around that, you need to figure a way to make the rest of your application wait until all the files are downloaded. For example:

```
var files = ["Bibliotheek S2.csv","Bibliotheek S8.csv","Euclides S23.csv","Lovelace Ledeganck.csv","Mercator S8.csv","Nadar S8.csv","Ortelius S8.csv","Practicum S2.csv","S12.csv","Thetis INW.csv","Turing S9.csv","Van Straelen S8.csv","Zuse S9.csv"];

files.forEach(function(f){
    d3.csv("lokalen/"+f,function(data){
      dt[f] = data;
      if (d3.keys(dt).length == files.length){
      // Whatever you'd like to do once you load all the data
      console.log(d3.keys(dt)) // For example to check our work 
      }
    });
});
```

When each file finishes loading, that if statement checks to see if all files have been stored in `dt`. If so, it works with all of the data; if not, no action is taken until the next file loads, when it checks again. The final file will execute whatever  you'd like to do with the full dataset.