# D3 - Loading data from a second CSV

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two separate CSV files, sharing an attribute:

**File 1**

```
name,total
Frank,13
Mary,24
Jim,46
```

**File 2**

```
name,desc
Frank,yellow
Mary,blue
Jim,green
```

How can I *map* the attribute `desc` to the File 1 so, let's say, when I hover on Frank, I will see "13" and "yellow"?

Currently, my code is looking like this:

```
d3.csv("data/csv/bilancio-missioni-desc.csv", function(descrizione) {
  data = descrizione.map(function(data){
            div.html("<h3>" + d.name + "</h3>" + "<p>" + data.desc + "</p>")
})
```

The problem is that `d.name` and `data.desc` (from File 1 and File 2) don't match — I can understand it's because I didn't combine them so they can *share* the common attribute `name`, but I don't know how to write the right piece of code.

**UPDATE**
My code so far:

```
d3.csv("data/csv/bilancio-tipologiedispesa-nest.csv", function(data1) {
d3.csv("data/csv/bilancio-missioni-desc.csv", function(data2) {
    //code that depends on both data1 and data2       
    data1.forEach(d => {
        data2.forEach(e => {
        if (d.name === e.name) {
        d.desc = e.desc;
    }
});
}); 
// Fade all the segments.
d3.selectAll("path")
.style("opacity", .3);
vis.selectAll("path")
.filter(function(node) {
    return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
})
.style("opacity", 1);
div.transition()
.duration(200)
.style("opacity", .9);
div.html("<h3>" + d.name + "</h3>" + "<p>" + d.desc + "</p>");
});
});
}
```

If I console.log(data1), "desc" (from data2) is appended to data1 (yay!). But "d.desc" is returning "unidefined" in the HTML.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have?

Comment: Hello @snolflake, I edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: @ValentinaRachiele regarding your update: `d3.csv` is asynchronous. So, any code that depends on `data1` has to be **inside** the inner `d3.csv`. That is, move all your code to below the `forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main approaches for loading several CSVs: using `d3.queue()` or nesting them:

```
d3.csv("file1.csv", function(data1) {
    d3.csv("file2.csv", function(data2) {
        //code that depends on both data1 and data2
    })
});
```

Where `data1` is the array from "file1.csv" and `data2` is the array from "file2.csv".

Then, we're gonna merge the two arrays based on their properties.

You can do this creating a third array or pushing the values in one of the two original arrays. Here, I'll do the second option (actually, the second option is what you asked: *"How can I "map" the attribute 'desc' to the File 1"*).

Have in mind that this is an *ad hoc* solution I made *specifically* to your problem (it will not work for another data structure):

```
data1.forEach(d => {
    data2.forEach(e => {
        if (d.name === e.name) {
            d.desc = e.desc
        }
    })
})
```

Now, `data1` has all the information you want: name, total and desc.

Here is a demo, check the console with the data (In this demo, I'm using a `<pre>` element to load the data, because I cannot use a CSV in the snippet):

```js
var data1 = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#file1").text());
var data2 = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#file2").text());

data1.forEach(d => {
    data2.forEach(e => {
        if (d.name === e.name) {
            d.desc = e.desc
        }
    })
})

console.log(data1);
```

```css
pre {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="file1">name,total
Frank,13
Jim,46
Mary,24</pre>
<pre id="file2">name,desc
Frank,yellow
Mary,blue
Jim,green</pre>
```

**PS**: If you files are too big, have a look at [@altocumulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190304/d3-loading-data-from-a-second-csv#comment69587956_41193922) alternative code in the comments below.

Comment: Nice solution putting those `<pre>` elements to use simulating external file content.

Comment: For the inner loop I'd prefer something like `data2.some(e => { return !!(d.name === e.name ? d.desc = e.desc : null) })` which allows you to break from that loop once a match is found. `.forEach()` on the other hand will always cycle through the entire array, which might not be a good idea for nested loops. If there are large amounts of data, this could significantly improve performance.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But modern browsers are so fast that, unless OP's array length is humongous, those micro-optimisations may have a negligible effect. However, as the length of the array is unknown, your code is indeed better.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my question, your answer helped me a lot, but I'm stucked again...

Comment: @ValentinaRachiele your problem now is very easy to solve: **any** code that depends on `data1` has to be **inside** the second (inner) `d3.csv` function.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, thank you. Playing with the code I had already understood that. So I moved the code inside the second function (honestly, I tried changing different positions)... But now both d.name and d.desc gives me only the last line of my CSVs (?).

Comment: No worries. Create a plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) with *all* your code, including the two CSVs, and I show you how to position it (put the csv files in "new file", on the left).

Comment: Here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/BGKz7MoPBeI3svDyJUq1?p=preview (thank you again!).

Comment: Well, there is no data binding in your code. What do you want to show in the sidebar? All the names and all the descs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130841/discussion-between-valentina-rachiele-and-gerardo-furtado).

Comment: Well, Valentina, unfortunately this turned out as a classic example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about your problem X, you asked about a solution Y, which doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Yep, I see. This was caused by my lack of expertise. I'm going to study more! Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Prego.

Answer (score 1):

As Gerardo Furtado has already laid out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41193922/4235784) you will have to resort to either using `d3.queue` or a nested version of `d3.csv` to keep loading your data in sync. When making use of two built-in features of D3 the nested approach can be refined to free you from doing explicit nested looping after the initial loading.

- Use a D3 [Map](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#maps) to provide for fast access to your data by the `name` property.
- Use a [row conversion function](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse) which may be passed as the second, optional parameter to [`d3.csv(url[[, row], callback])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#csv):

  > If a *row* conversion function is specified, the specified function is invoked for each row, being passed an object representing the current row (`d`)…

  This comes in particularly handy as the rows will internally be iterated over while parsing the file's content. You can use the row conversion function as a hook to be able to sync the second file's data to the first file's data by manipulating the map within that function.

I set up a [Block](http://bl.ocks.org/altocumulus/950d07be633c85bc9882718a6f0d72bb) demonstrating this approach:

```
d3.csv("file1.csv", function(data1) {
  // 1. Build a D3 map from your first file's contents 
  var map = d3.map(data1, function(d) { return d.name; });

  d3.csv("file2.csv", function(row) {
    // 2. Use the row function of the second file to match your data.
    map.get(row.name).desc = row.desc;  // 3. Sync data
    return null;   // 4. Don't append any row to the array.
  }, function() {  // 5. There is no parameter present; all data has been synced into data1.
    // Just logging below
    console.log(data1);  // [{ name: "Frank", total: "13", desc: "yellow"}, ...]
  })
});
```

Let me talk you through this step by step:

1. We build a map based on the parsed data from your first file, using the `name` property as the key.
2. When doing the inner loading of the second file we specify a row conversion as the second parameter. Normally, this will be used to do some data conversion and the like and return some converted object representing the actual row's data. In our scenario, however, we are not interested in the conversion itself, but in the implicit iteration and the access to the row's data.
3. We are now ready to sync the data by [getting](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#map_get) the object corresponding to this row's `name` from the map.
4. Returning `null` from the row conversion function will avoid building up an array for the second file, since we are not interested in a standalone version of the content:

   > If the returned value is null or undefined, the row is skipped and will be ommitted from the array…
5. Within the callback of the inner `d3.csv()` your data is ready and synced. Notice, that we are not passing any parameter to this callback, because we will access the synced data via `data1`. We will not even have to bother about the map anymore, which was but a means to allow fast access to our data from the first file. Because the map stores references to our data objects, we updated the actual objects from `data1`, which were used to build the map.

---

As a refinement, you might want to add some ES6 sugar making this even more concise ([ES6 Block](http://bl.ocks.org/altocumulus/039fd6e3f4f26fb2a53f031c5707472e)):

```
d3.csv("file1.csv", data1 => {
  let map = d3.map(data1, d => d.name);
  d3.csv("file2.csv",
         row => (map.get(row.name).desc = row.desc, null),
         () => {console.log(data1)}  // Merged data available at this point.
  );
});
```

Comment: Great idea using the row conversion function for that.

Comment: This ended up as another classic example of the XY problem. What OP really wanted cannot be done with this (see the comments in my answer and her plunker).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842384/importing-data-from-multiple-csv-files-in-d3) you can nest the csv loading function to to load the files asynchronously. Then you can combine them together:

```
var file1 = "data/csv/bilancio-missioni-desc.csv";
var file2 = "data/csv/bilancio-missioni-info.csv"; // I named it info just as an example

var div = d3.select('#my-div');
var data = {};

d3.csv(file1, function(descrizione) {
    d3.csv(file2, function(info) {
        processData(descrizione, info);
    })
})

function processData(descrizione, info) {
    descrizione.forEach(d => data[d.name] = d);
    info.forEach(i => data[i.name] && data[i.name]['desc'] = i.desc);
    appendData();
}

function appendData() {
    div.data(data).append(d => '<h3>' + d.name + ' (' + d.total ')</h3> <p>' + d.desc + '</p>');
}
```

This code might not work without a few adjustments of course, but I hope you get the idea. If not, let me know if there's something unclear to you. Good luck!

Comment: You were so kind! Tomorrow I'll try to play with your code – crossing all my fingers! I'll let you know if I can make it work. Thank you