# Visualizing data from different csv files in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am brand new to D3 and begin working on a new project. My question is this. I need to load two local CSV files and visualize them to two separate line charts(not multi-line charts)，which contain independent x axis and y axis. The final purpose is to compare these two charts with a vertical line penetrating both of them and both charts can be zooming or panning synchronously.

I created two SVGs for both of two separate charts and used two consecutive calls to `d3.csv()` to load two csv files such as

```
d3.csv("file1.csv", function(error, data) {
   //functions control the first chart 

});

d3.csv("file2.csv", function(error, dataㄉ) {
   //functions control the second chart

});
```

However, finally I found that contents inside the first `d3.csv()` cannot be used in the second `d3.csv()`.

Shouldn't I use different `svg`, or I need to apply new way to load two csv files but not using two independent `d3.csv()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842384/importing-data-from-multiple-csv-files-in-d3

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`d3.queue`](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) to load the files at the same time. The function in `.awaitAll()` is only evaluated after *both* CSV files have been loaded, and the function `.await()` only waits for *one* of the CSV files to complete loading.

```js
function delayedHello(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Hello!");
    callback(null);
  }, 250);
}

d3.queue()
  .defer(delayedHello)
  .defer(delayedHello)
  .awaitAll(function(error, data) {
    console.log(error ,data);
  });

d3.queue()
  .defer(delayedHello)
  .defer(delayedHello)
  .await(function(error, data) {
    console.log(error ,data);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is not fully correct: `.await()` does also wait until **all** tasks have finished. The difference between `.await()` and `.awaitAll()` is the way the results are passed on to the callback